# How to fix python: pip and django won't work (pkg.resource not found) on OS X with home dir on a different drive

Tags: python

I have an issue with my system: I have a small ssd, so I decided to move home to a different drive.

Everything works fine, but I cannot use neither pip, django nor any other python application, beside python itself, since I get an error all the time, saying

```
 pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.5.6
```

From what I can see, it is loading the application in /usr/local/bin/pip, but then I get errors about the distribution not found.
The path that is continuously printing in the error is `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py`

I was searching online to figure out the problem, and I can't find a way to actually fix this, because none of the solutions found here and on other sites, works.

I think that it has something to do with my home directory saved in a different drive? Plus I am updating OS X since 10.6; which results in my python getting update every time and I have probably 4-5 different version of it.
Probably the paths are totally messed up; and I would like to know how to fix this (either nuking everything and re-installing python, pip and everything else, or just fixing the path).

I need to use Django and Pip, so would be great if you could give me some advice about what to look for and what to change. I do not have much experience with how python works on the OS that host it; I just make simple apps with it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured out:

1) moved anything in /opt/local to ~/local

2) did an edit in my profile (.bash_profile), removing any line that was adding PATH, like macports entry

3) Installed homebrew and then did a `brew install python`

4) once done, if I run Pip it works fine now.

No clue why; probably the install of python re-wrote the old PATH file and replaced it with a new one. Isee that the version that now I am running on Mavericks is 2.6.9.

Hope that this help someone else that may experience the same issue.